# Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access. 0.000 sec

Tags: rdbms

This is my table named 'pet'.

```
SELECT * FROM pet;
```

[This is my table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqCDf.png)

When i try to load data into table 'pet'

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/pet.txt' 
INTO TABLE pet
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It throws the following error:

Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.   0.344 sec

Comment: 1. Please only tag a single RDBMS, 2. What exactly is your question?

Comment: We can't see your screen so we could only guess what the problem is. Please edit your question to include the actual MySQL statement you're trying to use - as text, not a screen shot.

Comment: The question has been edited.